# Sendmail - Sender verify failed

Tags: linux, sendmail

We are currently unable to send emails to other domains because the receiving host cannot verify the sender.

Emails are rejected with -

> <<< 550-Verification failed for
>
> <<< 550-No Such User Here
>
> <<< 550 Sender verify failed
>
> 550 5.1.1 ... User unknown
>
> <<< 503-All RCPT commands were rejected with this error:
>
> <<< 503-Sender verify failed

The server has been working fine up until yesterday when this problem suddenly occurred.  I've tried re-booting the server and the router but that hasn't helped.

me@mycompany.co.uk does exist and is receiving emails.  A check with http://verify-email.org/ returns

> MX record about mycompany.co.uk exists.
>
> Connection succeeded to mail.mycompany.co.uk SMTP.
>
> 220 server.mycompany.co.uk ESMTP Sendmail 8.14.7/8.14.1; Sat, 18 Feb 2017 09:07:24 GMT
>
> HELO verify-email.org
>   250 server.mycompany.co.uk Hello verify-email.org [verify-email.org] (may be forged), pleased to meet you
>
> MAIL FROM: 
>    =250 2.1.0 ... Sender ok
>
> RCPT TO: 
>    =250 2.1.5 ... Recipient ok
>
> <<< 503 Valid RCPT command must precede DATA

verify-email did report a problem last night.  It was unable to connect to mail.mycompany.co.uk so connected to the secondary MX instead.  I thought that might be the problem but it's connecting to mail.mycompany.co.uk now and the verification problem still exists.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since your stated problem is with sending out mail, that email verification is of no importance to you.  You are going to want to verify your reverse DNS record on your outgoing IP address, make sure it exists and that ideally the domain matches the domain your email server advertises itself as.  If that is good then do a blacklist check on your external IP, this can be done here:

https://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx

If its still not working verify your SPF record if you have one.